# How do we need 17 significant decimal digits to identify an arbitrary double-precision floating-point number?

Tags: floating-point, precision

Refer to link : https://www.exploringbinary.com/the-shortest-decimal-string-that-round-trips-examples/ . It says that a well-known result in computer science is that you need 17 significant decimal digits to identify an arbitrary double-precision floating-point number. Also, it uses below example

```
The floating point number 50388143.0682372152805328369140625 cannot be rounded to anything less than 17 digits and still round-trip. Rounded to 17 digits it’s 50388143.068237215, which converts back to our floating-point number. Rounded to 16 digits it’s 50388143.06823722, which is closer to the next floating-point number
```

This link is confusing me more and more. Lets say my number is 50388143.068237215**6**805328369140625
and if i round to 17 places then it becomes 50388143.068237216. How is it same as original number? I don't see it round tripping. Infact its different than the original number. What am i missing?

Comment: It's not the same as the original number, but the original number can be recovered by rounding `50388143.068237216` to the nearest representable IEEE 754 float. From the blog post you link to (emphasis mine): it's "a number that, **when converted back to floating-point**, gives you the original floating-point number"

Comment: @MarkDickinson - How can the original number can be recovered by rounding 50388143.068237216 to the nearest representable IEEE 754 floating point? Do you have any C++ code example showing the recovery and the  nearest representable IEEE 754 floating point?

Comment: @MarkDickinson -  Thanks. How to force rounding of 50388143.0682372156805328369140625 to give us 50388143.068237216? If i try to use std::cout on 50388143.0682372156805328369140625 then it gives me 50388143.068237215 and not 50388143.068237216.  Is this related to rounding strategy which is the culprit? How do i change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This link is confusing me more and more. Lets say my number is 50388143.0682372156805328369140625 and if i round to 17 places then it becomes 50388143.068237216. How is it same as original number?

> What am i missing?

"my number (as a `double`) is 50388143.068237215_6805328369140625" begins on a a false premise.

`double` can encode many values but not that one: 50388143.068237215_6805328369140625.  Instead code will use a nearby value: 50388143.068237215_2805328369140625.

Rounding that to 17 *significant* places *as text* becomes "50388143.06823721**5**".

Converting that text back to a `double` makes again a `double` with the value of 50388143.068237215_2805328369140625.

---

In general, if `double` --> *text* (using less than 17 *significant* decimal digits) --> `double`, is attempted, it may fail to result in the same `double`.

17 *significant* decimal digits is sufficient for all `double`.

Why 17 is tied to typical double encoding 53 significant *binary* digits (~9*10<sup>15</sup> combinations) and that the precision of decimal text values *wobbles* as compared to binary `double` ones.

Comment: Is there any easy way to determine if my double value will not be rounded to nearest value? I mean is there any c++ macro/helper to deduce that rounding to nearest value won't or will happen? You say that double value used by my original program can't be encoded. So I wanted to know if c++ has some macro/helper to determine that beforehand without doing any mathematics on bits?

Comment: @Test Not clear what you are asking in terms of a macro. Do you mean something like ISO-C's `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` which evaluates to 17 on systems using IEEE-754 binary floating-point arithmetic? That was adopted into C++ in C++11, I think.

Comment: @njuffa - what I meant is any helper macro/function in c++ which tells me that the double value I am trying to use can be directly represented by finite number of double bits or not without rounding to nearest value i.e no rounding will happen.

Comment: @Test The answer to that is "No".

Comment: @Test Perhaps try round tripping your _code_ value:  `char *s = "50388143.0682372152805328369140625"; double x = strtod(s,0); char buf[1000]; snprintf(buf, 1000, "%.99f, x); trim_trailing0(buf); directly_represented  = !strcmp(s, buf);`

Comment: How is "17" computed?

Comment: @chenzhongpu Research `DBL_DECMAL_DIG`, which is really the code needed than the magic number 17.  It is effectively near the rounded up `log10(pow(2, 53)`.  The more binary digits in a `double` significant, the more the `DBL_DECMAL_DIG`.  17 is just the most common.